# run a php script forever

Tags: php

I have a Cpanel web host without terminal and now I have PHP code that I want to run forever without any stops.
This code sends some requests and checks the response and then saves something in the database. I have written this code completely.
Please tell me a simple way to run this code non-stop or every second.

As i know, Cronjob for at least every minute. not for every seconds(or run forever).

I want a simple way to run a PHP code permanently on the server and not slow down the server.

Comment: `while(true) { /* your code */ }`. It's consuming resources though, so it WILL impact the server (it is impossible to have something actually "running" without having an impact on any resources)

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `Cron jobs`, please refer to this links for more information,

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cpanel/cpanel_cron_jobs.htm

https://docs.cpanel.net/cpanel/advanced/cron-jobs/

Comment: no, you don't need a cronjob... these are for recurring jobs, but it implies that the job eventually ends.

Comment: i think cronjob cant help me. Because I want to keep a program running once and forever. Or at least run every seconds.

Comment: that's the only way i can see it to do the job, you only need to choose the main file for the program and create Cron job and choose the interval time to run every second so the program keep running every second.

Comment: Abdel, cron jobs are unnecessary for that purpose. You can have a forever loop of the kind of `while (true) { /*your code here*/ }`

Comment: @LajosArpad There is timeout limit for php level and web server level.

Comment: @doraemon when you run it on command-line, there is no maximum execution time. You can also call `set_time_limit(0)` to directly set support for infinite execution.

Comment: @doraemon additionally, you can have a setting of `max_execution_time = 0` in php.ini.

Comment: @LajosArpad It is for php runtime and web server has its own limitation before going timeout error.

Comment: @doraemon Who said anything about webservers? Your very answer deals with cron jobs, so you also know we are not necessarily speaking about webservers. And the asker was speaking about a forever script being issued somehow, specifying that he has a CPanel with no terminal. So, no, webservers are of less relevance to this question until the asker says he/she wants to run it from a browser or wants it to serve some online requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can define 60 cronjobs to run every minutes. First one runs immediately, but second one sleep for a second, than run, 3rd one sleeps for two seconds etc.

Example Cron Command:

- - - - - sleep 1 && {your cron command to run your script} 2>&1

Alternatively you can use GNU package mcron or SystemD timer unit.

Answer (score 0):

An extremely simple way to achieve this is to have a forever loop, like this:

```
<?php

while (true) { //true will always be true
    //put here the code you want to be repeated forever
}
```